# Why does this var REQUEST ["name"] method always return null?

Tags: asp.net, razor, null, request, webmatrix

I'm self-learning how to create a form, pass the responses to a separate handler, and email them to my website account.  I have the form, which works, and oddly enough, I have the mail portion working.  However, this example is almost straight out of some ASP.NET help pages at Microsoft - yet it does not work, and I can't seem to find out why. What's wrong and how should it read instead?

Here's some form code:
{

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Mailform.cshtml" enctype="text/plain" 
        method="post" name="formcontent">
        <ul> 
            <li>
                <label for="name" class="heavyred">Contact Name: &nbsp</label>
                <input type="text"  name="contact" autofocus="true" size="40"
                    required="" /><span class="tinyfont">&nbsp red denotes a 
                    required field</span>
                <span class="italicfont"style="margin-left: 22%"><br>Person 
                    overseeing site development</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="strngweak">List strengths:<br></label>
                <textarea name="strngweak"  placeholder="420 chars max" 
                     cols="60" rows="7"></textarea>                    
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <input class="hyper buttn" style="margin-right:1%; font-size: 1em;
                "type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </div>     
    </form>        
</body>
```

}

handler.cshtml  code: (the first two requests end up NULL instead of getting data by name)

{

```
@{

 var contact = Request ["contact"];  <----- NULL instead of name=contact data
 var stweak = Request ["strngweak"]; <----- NULL instead of name=strngweak data

 var from = "info@portalmagician.com";
 var to = "sirrobcop@yahoo.com"; 
 var subject = "I WANT A WEBSITE";
 var msg = "From: ";            
 var errorMessage = "";
 var debuggingFlag = true;

 msg += contact + " Strengths: " + stweak;

 }

{ try-catch block initializes webmail helper and sends email here }

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    @if (IsPost) {

        if (errorMessage == "") {<p>Your message has been sent!</p>;}

        else {<p>Unable to send due server down or bad server info.</p>;}
    }        
</body>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `enctype` of your form to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or delete it).